# CardView dont show images propertly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, cardview

I have a problem displaying images in a CardView inside RecyclerView. It works when the image is an icon of AndroidStudio (example: ic_launcher) ...
ANDROID STUDIO: 2.3.3
I try copy other code examples but i cant do it, im medium begginer in java. Thanks you!

My code:
activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- A RecyclerView with some commonly used attributes -->

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />
```

row_layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:contentDescription="TODO"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/secondLine"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="26dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="Description"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/firstLine"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/secondLine"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Example application"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MyAdapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private List<String> values;

// Provide a reference to the views for each data item
// Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
// you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    public TextView txtHeader;
    public TextView txtFooter;
    public View layout;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        layout = v;
        txtHeader = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
        txtFooter = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
    }
}

public void add(int position, String item) {
    values.add(position, item);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

public void remove(int position) {
    values.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

// Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
public MyAdapter(List<String> myDataset) {
    values = myDataset;
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(
            parent.getContext());
    View v =
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
    // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    // - get element from your dataset at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element
    final String name = values.get(position);
    holder.txtHeader.setText(name);
    holder.txtHeader.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            remove(position);
        }
    });

    holder.txtFooter.setText("Footer: " + name);
}

// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return values.size();
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    // use this setting to
    // improve performance if you know that changes
    // in content do not change the layout size
    // of the RecyclerView
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    // use a linear layout manager
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    List<String> input = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        input.add("Test" + i);
    }// define an adapter
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(input);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```